# Cannot create an instance of an interface C#

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I am having an issue when trying to add an interface to a list of base interfaces when the base interface is of a certain type.

My interfaces are defined as below:

```
    public interface IWorkspace<out TWorkspace> where TWorkspace : IWorkspaceBaseModel { }
    public interface IWorkspaceBaseModel : IViewBaseModel { }
    public interface ILogCollectionViewModel : IWorkspace<IWorkspaceBaseModel> { }
```

I use the following code to get all the interfaces:

```
    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
       var workspaces = assembly
          .GetTypes()
          .Where(t => typeof(IWorkspace<IWorkspaceBaseModel>).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsInterface)
          .ToList();

       if (workspaces.Count > 0)
          foreach (var wvm in workspaces)
          {
             var myInterface = (IWorkspaceBaseModel)Activator.CreateInstance(wvm);
          }
    }
```

I am getting the error "Cannot create an instance of an interface." and when I the the following code:

```
    var myInterface = (IWorkspace<IWorkspaceBaseModel>)Activator.CreateInstance(wvm);
```

What i want to do then is add the interface to a list of base interfaces when the have been created:

```
    var viewList = new List<IWorkspaceBaseModel>();

    viewList.Add(myInterface);
```

Any help on how to fix this or a better way of doing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the posted code there's no **concrete class**, which is needed by `CreateInstance`. you cannot new a interface, neither when using reflection.

Comment: You should read up a little more on what an `interface` is and how to use it.

Comment: I tried finding the classes instead of interfaces by using .Where(t => typeof(IWorkspace<IWorkspaceBaseModel>).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface) instead but this didn't work either

Comment: sometimes an interface can only be from return value of some methods, not created instance. so it may be useless for you to find such constructor.

Comment: My concrete classes are: LogCollectionViewModel : WorkspaceBaseModel, ILogCollectionViewModel { } and  WorkspaceBaseModel : IWorkspaceBaseModel { }

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly your intention was, but you can only create instances of classes (that can implement your interfaces).

It's also not possible to write (if IViewModel is an interface):

```
var myInstance = new IViewModel();
```

You can find classes that implement an interface:

```
var assembly = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var classes = assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(type => type.ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i == typeof(IPageViewModel)));
```

If you want to create an instance afterwards, you also have to check for non-abstract classes.

Comment: I am trying to get all my interfaces that inherit IWorkspaceBaseModel and add them to a list so i can use them for navigation

Comment: If you want to get interfaces, you need to check if the type is an interface.

type => type.ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i == typeof(IPageViewModel)) && type.IsInterface

Comment: if i do this and try to add the interface to my list I get an "Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'InterfaceAssemblyTest.IWorkspaceBaseModel'" message